# Joi validation regex for a specific value or a list of specific values

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, joi

I am converting CSV to JSON and I need to validate a cell value.
Having a list of possible valid values `['abc', 'def', 'ref', 'rop']`. I want to write a regex assuming a valid cell would be either

1. one value from the above list (e.g. `validValue='abc'` `notValidValue='adr'`)
   or
2. multiple values from the above list separated by `\\\` (e.g. `validValue='abc \\\ ref \\\ def'` `notValidValue='aef \\\ kop'`)

I tried with `Joi.string().regex(/(?:abc|def|ref|rop)(/s\\\\\\/s(?:abc|def|ref|rop))?/)` but it throws eeror for first `/s` -> invalid character and also `Argument of type RegExp is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | StringRegexOptions'....`

Answer (score 0):

You have typo. The `/s` should be `\s`.
And the tail `?` will match the second part 0 or once.  Change it to `*` can match as many time as it will. or you want to specify the maximum `{0,3}`.

```
regex(/(?:abc|def|ref|rop)(\s\\\\\\\s(?:abc|def|ref|rop))*/)
```

Comment: Ok typo was an error. But this regex is still not working correctly. It didn't match exactly the words, so needed to add anchors: /(?:^abc$|^def$|^ref$|^rop$)(\s\\\\\\\s(?:^abc$|^def$|^ref$|^rop$))?/. BUT now it turns values which are abc \\\ def as wrong ones

Comment: Could you give me some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Add `^` and `$` to your key word is not correct, it should be `/^(?:abc|def|ref|rop)(\s\\\\\\\s(?:abc|def|ref|rop))?$/`